# Raphael js-onclick action that changes color?remain that color until returning to click in other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, raphael

I commented. I have problems with this library because it is the first time I use it. It took a couple of hours looking solution but I not find it.

I need to change the color on mouseover to X color and back to original when no mouseover.

On click change to Y color and remain so until you make another click, and mouseover keep it running.

I have been guided by this example whit svg map: http://totaki.com/poesiabinaria/2014/10/crear-mapas-html5-interactivos-con-raphaeljs/

This is my code:

```
<link href="includes/css_includes/noticias_index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <head>
    <title>Ejemplo Raphaeljs</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js_includes/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js_includes/raphael-min.js"></script>
  </head>

<div class="contenido_noti">

    <h1>RESULTADOS ELECCIONES 2012 - MUNICIPIOS</h1>

<center>
<table width="1180" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">MAPA</th>
    <th scope="col" style="text-align:center">ESTADISTICAS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" width="">    <div id="lienzo">

    </div></th>
    <th scope="col" width="650" style="text-align:left">
    <div id="municipiotxt"><img id="loadingicon" src="img_main/selecciona.png" /></div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
   <script>
      var municipios_data = {
    'ph1': 'Cadereyta de Montes',
    'ph2': 'Jalpan de Serra',
    'ph3': 'Colón',
    'ph4': 'Querétaro',
    'ph5': 'Pinal de Amoles',
    'ph6': 'Arroyo Seco',
    'ph7': 'Peñamiller',
    'ph8': 'El Marqués',
    'ph9': 'Tolimán',
    'ph10': 'Landa de matamoros',
    'ph11': 'Tequisquiapan',
    'ph12': 'Pedro Escobedo',
    'ph13': 'Ezequiel Montes',
    'ph14': 'San Joaquín',
    'ph15': 'Corregidora',
    'ph16': 'Huimilpan',
    'ph17': 'San Juan del Río',
    'ph18': 'Amealco de Bonfil'};

      var default_attributes = {
            fill: '#999999',
            stroke: '#000000',
            'stroke-width': 1,
        };  
      var $munictxt = $('#municipiotxt');

      $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/mapas/Mapa_muni.svg',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
      var rjs = Raphael('lienzo', 570, 670);
      var corr="";
      $(xml).find('svg > g >  path').each(function() {
        var path = $(this).attr('d');
    var pid = $(this).attr('id');
    var pid_select="";
        var munic = rjs.path(path);

        munic.attr(default_attributes);
                /*funcion de hover*/
        munic.hover(function() {    


          this.animate({ fill: '#00bbff' });

        }, /*funcion al moverso mouse*/ function() {


          this.animate({ fill: default_attributes.fill});


        })      /*funcion de click*/ .click(function() {
         var muni_query=municipios_data[pid];
         muni_select=pid;
$("#municipiotxt").load("includes/querys_includes/mapa_muni_SVG_QUERY.php",{muni_query:muni_query});
   $munictxt.html(muni_select);
          this.animate({ fill: '#FF0000' });

        });
          });
    }
      });

    </script>

</div>
```

Sorry if my english is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me just give you a brief example on how you could do it:
http://jsfiddle.net/x0pv7580/

I create all needed elements...

```
var rect1 = paper.rect(20,30,100,12).attr({fill: "orange"});   
...
```

and push them into an array:

```
var elements = [rect1, rect2, rect3];
....
```

After that, every elements gets the mouse actions:

```
for(var i = 0; i< elements.length; i++) {
  appendActionToElement(elements[i]);
}
```

These are the key actions:

```
function appendElement(element) {


  element.mouseover(function () {   //on mouseover change to color X
    this.attr('fill', 'green');
  });

  element.mouseout(function () {    //on mouseout change color depending on status
    if(!this.active)
      this.attr('fill', 'orange');
    else
      this.attr('fill', 'white');
  });

  element.click(function() {
    this.attr('fill', 'white');   //white should be your color Y
    this.active = true;           //set it active
    for(var i = 0; i< elements.length; i++) {
      if(elements[i] != this) {      //very important, on click we loop through all elements
        elements[i].active = false;  //and set them inactive and orange.
        elements[i].attr('fill', 'orange');
      }

    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It has helped me to follow the code. Achieve to make a comparison in the for-if but only compares variables not access the object or element "municipios_data" to change the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! It has helped me to follow the code. Achieve to make a comparison in the for-if but only compares variables not access the object or element "municipios_data" to change the attributes.

```
 <script>
      var municipios_data = {
    'ph1': 'Cadereyta de Montes',
    'ph2': 'Jalpan de Serra',
    'ph3': 'Colón',
    'ph4': 'Querétaro',
    'ph5': 'Pinal de Amoles',
    'ph6': 'Arroyo Seco',
    'ph7': 'Peñamiller',
    'ph8': 'El Marqués',
    'ph9': 'Tolimán',
    'ph10': 'Landa de matamoros',
    'ph11': 'Tequisquiapan',
    'ph12': 'Pedro Escobedo',
    'ph13': 'Ezequiel Montes',
    'ph14': 'San Joaquín',
    'ph15': 'Corregidora',
    'ph16': 'Huimilpan',
    'ph17': 'San Juan del Río',
    'ph18': 'Amealco de Bonfil'};
    /*----*/
      var default_attributes = {
            fill: '#999999',
            stroke: '#000000',
            'stroke-width': 1,
        };  
    /*----*/
      var $munictxt = $('#municipiotxt');
    /*----*/

      $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/mapas/Mapa_muni.svg',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
      var rjs = Raphael('lienzo', 570, 670);
      var corr="";
      $(xml).find('svg > g >  path').each(function() {
        var path = $(this).attr('d');
    var pid = $(this).attr('id');
        var munic = rjs.path(path);
    munic.attr(default_attributes);

    munic.mouseover(function () {   //hover
   this.animate({ fill: '#00bbff' });
  });

  munic.mouseout(function () {    //mouse out
    if(!this.active)
   this.animate({ fill: default_attributes.fill});
    else
    this.animate({ fill: 'red' });
  });

  munic.click(function() {

         var muni_query=municipios_data[pid];
         var muni_select=pid;
$("#municipiotxt").load("includes/querys_includes/mapa_muni_SVG_QUERY.php",{muni_query:muni_query});
   $munictxt.html(muni_select);


     this.animate({ fill: 'red' });  
    this.active = true;     

    for(var i = 1; i< 18; i++) {
        posicion = 'ph'+i;
        //alert(municipios_data[posicion])
        //alert(municipios_data[pid])
        alert(this)
      if(municipios_data[posicion] != municipios_data[pid]) {
          //alert("si")


        municipios_data[posicion].attr('fill', 'orange');
        municipios_data[posicion].active = false;
      }

    }


  });                           
          });                         
    }
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want but I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
var ab = ["a", "b"];
var p = Raphael(0,0,(ab.length * 150),300);
function resetColor() {
  ab.map(function(notActive) {
    return notActive.attr({fill: "red"});
  });  
}
function colorChange(o) {
  o.attr({fill: "blue"})
}
for (i=0; i<ab.length; i++) {
  ab[i] = p.circle(75 + (i*150),150,75).attr({fill: "red"}).click(function(){
    active = this,
    resetColor(),
    this.attr({fill : "green"})
  }).hover(function(){
    this.attr({fill : "green"})
  }, function(){
    resetColor(),
    colorChange(active)
  });
}
```

UPDATE:

Sorry I understood you wanted to keep the mouseOver running after clicking
http://jsfiddle.net/crockz/k4sgk7sa/

If you want to break the mouseOver with active colour, replace the green with blue on the click function

```
this.attr({fill : "blue"})
```

fiddle just for reference:
http://jsfiddle.net/crockz/Ldkm0aju/